# Twitter get request with API key iOS 7

Tags: twitter, ios7, api-key

I have received my API key for the twitter API. 
Currently my request looks like this

NSString *twitterURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=xyz&count=20"];

Now how do I build my request url with my API key?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) library.

```
STTwitterAPI *twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerKey:@""
                                                      consumerSecret:@""
                                                          oauthToken:@""
                                                    oauthTokenSecret:@""];

[twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {

    [_twitter getSearchTweetsWithQuery:@"xyz"
                          successBlock:^(NSDictionary *searchMetadata, NSArray *statuses) {
                              NSLog(@"-- statuses: %@", statuses);
                          } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                              NSLog(@"-- error: %@", error);
                          }];

} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"-- error: %@", error);
}];
```